# every android app closes unexpectedly

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, mobile, builder

I started building an app for android and debugging it through usb using flash builder 4.5.1, but after a while it said "the app was closed unexpectedly" on my android machine.
The strange thing is, it doesn't crash. It just says it's crashing, but when I click 'force close', it just keeps running like normal.

I just tried to debug a brand new flex mobile project, without any coding, and after a couple of seconds it also said it had stopped unexpectedly.

I have no idea if I'm doing something wrong, or if somthing bigger is going on here.

Comment: If you're running in debug mode and have a breakpoint stop the application; this dialog almost always pops up for me.  It makes sense, because a breakpoint, in essence, stops the application from functioning while it waits for your input.  I've never selected "Force Close" and have it keep the app open.

Comment: Flextras is right, just continue on the breakpoint before the timeout occurs (15-20 seconds if I remember), or else Android thinks that your application is unresponsive.

Comment: unfortunately, it happens without any breakpoints added to the debugger. I even tried just running the app, not going into debugger mode, but even then it appears after 10-15 seconds, without anything really happening.. : \

Answer (score 0):

I found the use of trace or Alert.show to be helpful in this regard, simply because of the annoyance of pausing an application state too long can cause problems.

I use a custom Alert - sample provided

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="AlertMsg">
        <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer x="70" y="300">
            <s:TitleWindow title="My Message" close="close()">
                <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                    <s:Label text="My alert message text here..."/>
                    <s:Button label="OK" click="close()"/>
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:TitleWindow>
        </s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" gap="10"
                      horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top"/>
</s:layout>

<s:TextArea text="This sample shows how you can display a simple alert message in a mobile application using the Spark SkinnablePopUpContainer. The mx.controls.Alert is not recommended for mobile."
            width="98%" editable="false"/>
<s:Button label="Show Alert" click="(new AlertMsg()).open(this, false)"/>
```

Comment: I'm not using any breakpoints, so that's not the problem.. Also, you can't use Alert.show in android apps (I think)..

Comment: Updated my answer to show you my lame custom Alert toy that I use. ;)

Comment: You android machine is its a virtual test bench or is it a phone or tablet, and if so is it running Custom Firmware, that often causes interference with permissions.

I cant run my AirApps on my Custom rom Device.

Comment: thanks for the example, looks like a decent alternative.
It's an HTC Desire, no custom firmware, bought it 2 months ago, haven't even got the time yet to tamper with it.. ^^'

Comment: Tampering shall happen ;)

ok so back to your app and why its crashing are you using the latest flex 4.5 all frameworks up to date, and is your air player up to date?

Comment: I updated FB just before I started working on the app, which was 2 weeks ago. AIR installed itself on my HTC when I plugged it in for debugging also 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I also just tried a release build on my HTC, which worked fine without any of the "unexpectedly close"-"force close" hiccups.. I may not have a solution for the hiccup in usb-mode, but at least I know now that it won't affect my final release build.. : \

Comment: Well really debugging via usb would be nice, but worst case you can just use alerts or text boxes bound to relevant stuff.

Good luck and Im sure later versions will fix that, air itself runs fine.